# Workitem Export using Polarion API

Tags: polarion

I have a requirement with respect to Polarion. We need a script that will export all workitems from Polarion to Excel Format on daily basis using Job scheduler.

Expecting suggestions to implement this scenario.

Comment: what is your problem? there is a IJob example in SDK available. Generate a Excel or a .csv file and copy it into the apache folder and output in the joblog the URL?

Comment: Peter Parker
I am able to export workitems to Excel. But i want to download the Excel in particular folder.(E://Workitems/export)

Comment: You need to use a servlet which exports the data as .xlsx file. The servlet will be accessible via a separate URL(with or without login). you can use a tool like curl to access the URL and download the xls file.
The User Interface is not remote-scriptable, if that was your question.

Comment: Yes Exactly.i want the Same.

Comment: For this you need to modify an extension. Check the polarion SDK either for job extension or servlet extension. Creating an excelsheet is not part of the SDK examples.